# Automated delegation in Java

Tags: java, delegates

I would like to add some functionality to an object that will be generated at runtime.  However, the interface for this object is very large (and not under my control).  I would like to wrap the object in my own class which adds the functionality I want and delegates the standard interface functionality to the original object - is there any way to do this in Java without creating a 1-line copy-paste delegator method for every method in the interface?

What I want to avoid:

```
class MyFoo implements Foo {
  Foo wrapped;

  void myMethod() { ... }

  void interfaceMethod1() wrapped.interfaceMethod1();
  int interfaceMethod2() wrapped.interfaceMethod2();
  // etc etc ...
}
```

What I would prefer:

```
class MyFoo implements Foo {
  Foo wrapped;

  void myMethod() { ... }

  // automatically delegate undefined methods to wrapped object
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [dynamic proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) and intercept merely the methods you want to override.

> A dynamic proxy class is a class that implements a list of interfaces
>   specified at runtime such that a method invocation through one of the
>   interfaces on an instance of the class will be encoded and dispatched
>   to another object through a uniform interface. Thus, a dynamic proxy
>   class can be used to create a type-safe proxy object for a list of
>   interfaces without requiring pre-generation of the proxy class, such
>   as with compile-time tools. *Method invocations on an instance of a
>   dynamic proxy class are dispatched to a single method in the
>   instance's invocation handler*, and they are encoded with a
>   java.lang.reflect.Method object identifying the method that was
>   invoked and an array of type Object containing the arguments

(my emphasis)

By implementing [InvocationHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) you simply create one method that receives every invocation on that object (effectively what you've described above)

Comment: +1, exactly what I would use. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12486028/646634) for some code examples.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  Brian, your examples were also quite useful!

Comment: Is it possible to have compile-time proxies?