# Is there a Java wrapper annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

Trying to find a way to wraps an object, which is auto generated based on some model with lots of getters and setters. For example:

```
class ObjectToWrap {

    public int getIntA();

    public int getIntB();

    ... // Tons of other getters
}
```

I **have** to create a wrapper that wraps this object and use some annotation that generates methods from `ObjectToWrap` for me. Code looks like the following:

```
class Wrapper {
    private ObjectToWrap obj;

    public int getIntA() {
        return obj.getIntA();
    }

    public int getIntB() {
        return obj.getIntB();
    }

    ... // Tons of other getters
}
```

Is there an annotation to do this? I just don't want to make the code look lengthy.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13348215/1686330 Btw., what you are trying to achive is to auto create delegate methods: https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Delegation_pattern.html

Comment: @Zhuinden, what exact annotation were you referring to?

Comment: That is called delegating, and when those generated classes were interfaces go for @DirkLachowski's link, dynamic proxies.

Comment: @DirkLachowski Not a duplicate of that question at all. This one is about annotations. Different altogether.

Comment: @user207421 No, this question (you have realized that it's 9 years old, right?) is about autogenerating a delegate and the OP mentions annotations as an option. I commented nearly a decade ago to point them to delegates because the question made me wonder if OP maybe didn't know the concept. While the accepted answer mentioning Lombok is correct, what OP really needs is to learn what delegation is, because if they would have known about it, the question would have been "Is there an annotation that can generate a delegate?" and then it would have been flagged for closure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at Project Lombok which has a @Delegate annotation which does exactly what you want.

[@Delegate documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate)

I think you would be able to do this:

```
import lombok.Delegate;
class Wrapper {
    //the types field in the annotation says
    //to only auto generate deleagate methods
    //for only the public methods in the ObjectToWrap class
    //and not any parent classes if ObjectToWrap extended something 
    @Delegate(types = ObjectToWrap.class)
    private ObjectToWrap obj;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **maven** build infrastructure with dependency management, you could have a dependent sub-project that collects the generated sources as-is (not as code). Another sub-project could then generate real sources out of them (**source code transformation**) as zip, which then could be imported by maven in the main project as pre-compile target.

On that basis you could use dynamic proxy classes, or even immediate generated classes.

---

The only other alternative would be to use the **java scripting** API, and do the business in JavaScript or so. Loosing the type safeness of java and lowering the software quality.

Unfortunately the alternative of hybrid usage of **another JVM language** I cannot consider productive. The very nice and powerful Scala still is too wild/complex/ticklish.